# Commutator subgroup of group generated by 2 elements

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to prove the following: Let $G$ be a group with generators $a$ and $b$. If $w=a^{n_{1}}b^{m_{1}}\cdots a^{n_{k}}b^{m_{k}}$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{k} n_{i} = \sum_{i=1}^{k} m_{i} =0$, then $w$ lies in the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ of $G$. I'm trying induction on $k$ but I struggle. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with induction on $k$ is that if you want to prove the $k + 1$ case, the sums of the $n_i$ and $m_i$ from $1$ to $k$ are not necessarily zero, so you can't apply the inductive hypothesis. Here's a proof:

You can check that for any group $G$, the quotient $G/[G,G]$ is defined (i.e. $[G,G]$ is normal) and abelian. Let $G' = G/[G,G]$, and let $N$ and $M$ denote the sum of the $n_i$ and $m_i$ respectively. We have
$$wG' = (a^{n_1}b^{m_1}\cdots a^{n_k}b^{n_k})G' = (a^Nb^M)G' = G',$$
where the fact that $G'$ is abelian is used to rearrange the $a^{n_i}$ and $b^{m_i}$ in the second equality and the fact that $N = M = 0$ is used in the last equality. Now $wG' = G'$ implies $w \in [G,G]$.